# Compiling React component with rollup is returning webpack error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, jsx, rollupjs

I'm trying to compile a React jsx components throught Rollup.js to fill my components library in commonjs.

This is my rollup configuration

```
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';

export default {
  input: ['./src/xxx.jsx'],
  output: [
    {
      dir: './public/build/lib/xxx/commonjs/',
      format: 'esm',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    resolve({
      browser: true,
      preferBuiltins: false,
      extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.json', '.node', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    }),
    babel({
      exclude: './node_modules/**',
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
      plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'],
      babelHelpers: 'runtime',
    }),
    commonjs(),
    postcss({
      extensions: ['.css'],
    }),
    image(),
    json(),
  ],
};
```

On rollup compilation i get no error, but just this warning

> (!) Circular dependencies node_modules/@rjsf/core/dist/es/utils.js ->
> node_modules/@rjsf/core/dist/es/components/fields/index.js ->
> node_modules/@rjsf/core/dist/es/components/fields/ArrayField.js ->
> node_modules/@rjsf/core/dist/es/utils.js
> node_modules/@rjsf/core/dist/es/utils.js ->
> node_modules/@rjsf/core/dist/es/components/fields/index.js ->
> node_modules/@rjsf/core/dist/es/components/fields/BooleanField.js ->
> node_modules/@rjsf/core/dist/es/utils.js
> node_modules/@rjsf/core/dist/es/utils.js ->
> node_modules/@rjsf/core/dist/es/components/fields/index.js ->
> node_modules/@rjsf/core/dist/es/components/fields/MultiSchemaField.js
> -> node_modules/@rjsf/core/dist/es/utils.js ...and 19 more

But when i want to import my component into another app, i have thoses errors concerning webpack but from where it come from ?

> Compiled with problems:X
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@xxx/xxx/xxx.js 1:0-32
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in
> 'C:\dev\Test\my-app\node_modules@xxx\xxx'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
> - install 'stream-http' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:     resolve.fallback: { "http": false
>   }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@xxx/xxx/xxx.js 2:0-33
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in
> 'C:\dev\Test\my-app\node_modules@xxx\xxx'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
> - install 'https-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:    resolve.fallback: { "https":
>   false }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@xxx/xxx/xxx.js 3:0-31
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in
> 'C:\dev\Test\my-app\node_modules@xxx\xxx'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
> - install 'url' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:     resolve.fallback: { "url": false }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@xxx/xxx/xxx.js 4:0-34
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in
> 'C:\dev\Test\my-app\node_modules@xxx\xxx'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
> - install 'stream-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:   resolve.fallback: {
>   "stream": false }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@xxx/xxx/xxx.js 5:0-32
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in
> 'C:\dev\Test\my-app\node_modules@xxx\xxx'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
> - install 'assert' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:  resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@xxx/xxx/xxx.js 6:0-30
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in
> 'C:\dev\Test\my-app\node_modules@xxx\xxx'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
> - install 'browserify-zlib' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:     resolve.fallback: { "zlib":
>   false }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@xxx/xxx/xxx.js 7:0-28
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in
> 'C:\dev\Test\my-app\node_modules@xxx\xxx'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
> - install 'crypto-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:   resolve.fallback: {
>   "crypto": false }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@xxx/xxx/xxx.js 8:0-30
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\dev\Test\my-app\node_modules@xxx\xxx'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@xxx/xxx/xxx.js 9:0-32
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in
> 'C:\dev\Test\my-app\node_modules@xxx\xxx'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
> - install 'path-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:     resolve.fallback: { "path":
>   false }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@xxx/xxx/xxx.js 10:0-34
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in
> 'C:\dev\Test\my-app\node_modules@xxx\xxx'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@xxx/xxx/xxx.js 12:0-34
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in
> 'C:\dev\Test\my-app\node_modules@xxx\xxx'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
> - install 'buffer' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:  resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@xxx/xxx/xxx.js 13:0-32
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in
> 'C:\dev\Test\my-app\node_modules@xxx\xxx'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
> - install 'util' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:    resolve.fallback: { "util": false }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@xxx/xxx/xxx.js
> 123470:44-83
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../include/module.js' in
> 'C:\dev\Test\my-app\node_modules@xxx\xxx'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@xxx/xxx/xxx.js
> 123471:44-83
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../include/action.js' in
> 'C:\dev\Test\my-app\node_modules@xxx\xxx'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@xxx/xxx/xxx.js
> 162102:17-48
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ajv-i18n/localize/fr' in
> 'C:\dev\Test\my-app\node_modules@xxx\xxx'
>
> ERROR in
> ./node_modules/string_decoder/node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js
> 4:13-30
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in
> 'C:\dev\Test\my-app\node_modules\string_decoder\node_modules\safe-buffer'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
> - install 'buffer' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:  resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I had the same issue, and then realized that I was importing a module into my component library that was intended to run in a node environment. Removing that package solved the issue, except of course now I need that package.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by adding `resolve: ({ browser : true })` to rollup.config.js which I see you already have added.

Another solution that worked for me was to use:
https://github.com/FredKSchott/rollup-plugin-polyfill-node

To use this plugin modify your rollup.config.js as follows

```
import nodePolyfills from 'rollup-plugin-polyfill-node';

...

export default {

  ...

  resolve: ({ 
    preferBuiltins: false 
  }),

  ...

  plugins: [
    nodePolyfills()
  ],

  ...

};
```

This will include these "missing" libraries in your bundle.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I was having same issue and was struck for days it came like a life saver for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace imported @rollup/node-plugin-resolve
from :

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
```

To:

```
import {nodeResolve} from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
```

And replace it in plugins:

```
nodeResolve({
  extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
}),
```

It's worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried several fixes, including trying to polyfill it by using https://github.com/ionic-team/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills, but I couldn't get it working.

I am also exporting both commonjs and esm. What worked for me was to add `broswer: true`, `preferBuiltins: false`, and change the order of the plugins. This is my final solution, which correctly works for both ESM & CJS:

```
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json'

export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: [
    {
      dir: 'dist/esm',
      format: 'esm',
      exports: 'named',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    {
      dir: 'dist/cjs',
      format: 'cjs',
      exports: 'named',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve({
      browser: true,
      preferBuiltins: false,
    }),
    commonjs(),
    json(),
  ],
}
```